# How to dynamically highlight the SIDE of a road (or draw a line next to) with google maps or mapquest on Android

Tags: android, api, maps, highlight

I'm trying to highlight the odd or even side of the street (for at least the block) the user is on (or all streets, if that is simpler.)

I can find the odd or even side, I've figured that out, but drawing a line parallel to the road is proving problematic.  I devised a method using google maps and geocoding to find points at the ends of the block on the odd or even side and draw a line between them, but all that geocoding is slow and unreliable.  It works great at my apartment, but falls on its face in many locations.

Is there a way to put a 2nd road overlay on top of the map shifted north or south and east or west and change the road colors?

I am open to using google or mapquest api if either provides a useful feature.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Something like traffic overlay where you can color the side of the street based on a situation.

Comment: I think there's no way, I been worked a lot with google maps, a trafic overlay can helps you?

Comment: Google Maps or any other API

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Google Maps API to figure you street coordinates, then you can shift them off and draw the line using a `Polyline` [Info here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes)

Comment: How would you shift them off ? Manually ?

Comment: @Mehdi.Sqalli you'd have to figure out where left/right is then you can dynamically shift off the gps coordinates using a method. Or you do it manually if that suffices for your app

Comment: I have a large set of data. So the ideal would be to do it automatically. The problem is I can't see a way to figure out where is the left/right of the street based on the data Google API sends me.

Comment: Does it have to be one of of them or can you randomly choose? What is even right. Google Maps can't ship this data since perpective comes into play. Turn 180° and left will be right